# How to write a vhdl code for a 4 bit adder/subtractor

Tags: vhdl, quartus

this code is given as the code for a 16 bit adder. I want to modify this to be 4 bit and also subtractor. Right now Im a little stuck on what some of these lines of code do. Im assuming 15DOWNTO0 is what turns x into x0,x1,x2.. until x15. I am confused though because in Signal sum it then becomes 16DOWNTO0 so I was wondering why its 16 instead of 15. I also do not understand what overflow represents. Lastly, what does `(’0’&X)`  mean/do?
I realize I asked a lot of question so thanks in advance!

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std logic 1164.all;
USE ieee.std logic unsigned.all;
ENTITY adder16 IS
PORT ( Cin : IN STD LOGIC;
X, Y : IN STD LOGIC VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
S : OUT STD LOGIC VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
Cout, Overflow : OUT STD LOGIC );
END adder16 ;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF adder16 IS
SIGNAL Sum : STD LOGIC VECTOR(16 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
Sum < = (’0’&X) + (’0’&Y) + Cin;
S < = Sum(15DOWNTO0);
Cout < = Sum(16);
Overflow < = Sum(16) XOR X(15) XOR Y(15) XOR Sum(15);
END Behavior;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the difficulty you're having?

Comment: @user16145658 Right now Im a little stuck on what some of these lines of code do. Im assuming 15DOWNTO0 is what turns x into x0,x1,x2.. until x15. I am confused though because in Signal sum it then becomes 16DOWNTO0 so I was wondering why its 16 instead of 15. I also do not understand what overflow represents. Lastly, what does (’0’&X)  mean/do? I realize I asked a lot of question so thanks in advance

Comment: No. `X, Y : IN STD LOGIC VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);` declares ports X and Y of array type std_logic_vector with an index range of 15 downto 0. There's a requirement  that numeric literals and identifiers are separated (e.g. a space). `S <= SUM(15 downto 0);` assigns the SUM array slice of  elements 15 downto 0 to output port S.  (VHDL is only character case sensitive in extended identifiers and character literals). Having SUM larger than S allows the carry out to be expressed. The length returned by the binary operator "+" is the longest of it's two operands. Overflow can occur in signed arithmetic.

Comment: @user16145658 thank you so much this helps a lot. just one more question if its okay, what does (’0’&X) do?

Comment: The concatenation operator joins values of array types with other values of the same array type or the array type's element type. Here X is a value of a constrained array type which concatenate from the left with a value of '0' as the element type  of std_logic_vector. The type of '0' (which can be overloaded) is determined by context (the type of X, the right operand). Making a smaller adder involves reducing the left bounds of X, Y, S and  SUM and selecting the new left bounds for Cout, S and calculating Overflow. `<=` is a compound delimiter made of two consecutive characters with no space.

Comment: @user16145658 I think I got it now thank you so much. I have done some simple code on vhdl before but not like this one and the error messages werent making sense. Youve been a tremendous help I couldnt thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 4 bits adder, you must change the values of your vectors:

```
STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
```

You have in your code `(15 downto 0)` because counting the bit 0 to 15 it counts 16 bits. The overflow bit will be set to '1' in the case the last most significative bit has a carry.

Your 4-bit adder should look like that:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
ENTITY adder4 IS
PORT ( Cin : IN STD_LOGIC;
X, Y : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
S : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
Cout, Overflow : OUT STD_LOGIC );
END adder4 ;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF adder4 IS
SIGNAL Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
Sum <= (’0’&X) + (’0’&Y) + Cin;
S <= Sum(3 DOWNTO 0);
Cout <= Sum(4);
Overflow <= Sum(4) XOR (X(3) XOR Y(3) XOR Sum(3));
END Behavior;
```

Probably you are using the signal sum of 5 bits to detect the overflow in your most significative bit '1XXXX' as you assigned Carry out to Sum(4). This solution is based on your structure but you could try others even easier.

You can use a `generic` if you want to change the bits of your adder just changing a number on your code:

```
......
ENTITY adderN IS
GENERIC (N : INTEGER := 4); "Where can be 16, 4 or any number of bits"
PORT ( Cin : IN STD_LOGIC;
X, Y : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
S : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
Cout, Overflow : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END adderN ;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF adderN IS
SIGNAL Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
Sum < = (’0’&X) + (’0’&Y) + Cin;
S < = Sum(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
Cout < = Sum(N);
Overflow < = Sum(N) XOR X(N-1) XOR Y(N-1) XOR Sum(N-1);
END Behavior;
```